# mysql modify duplicated fields

Tags: mysql, duplicates

I have a table (products) with duplicate products_model field . 
I need to change them to some new value. 
I can select them: `SELECT * FROM products GROUP BY products_model HAVING count(*) >=2`

I need to change `products_model = products_model + RANDOM NUMBER`

Thank you

Comment: I'm afraid this can't be done the way you expect it to. I could come up with an update statement, that would add random numbers to the products_model, but as those numbers are random, it could not be guaranteed that the number is not the same for two of the same products models.

Comment: OK, or some unique value like products_model = products_model + products_id

Answer (score 0):

Given that both fields are VARCHARS this does the job, concatenating products_model and products_id with an underscore

```
update products p1,
    products p2 
set 
    p1.products_model = concat(p1.products_model, '_', p1.products_id),
    p2.products_model = concat(p2.products_model, '_', p2.products_id)
where
    p1.products_model = p2.products_model
        and p1.products_id > p2.products_id
```

Before:

```
id products_model products_id
1   A   a
2   A   b
3   B   a
4   C   a
5   C   b
```

After:

```
id products_model products_id
1   A_a a
2   A_b b
3   B   a
4   C_a a
5   C_b b
```

Answer (score 0):

This uses variables to assign a sequential number to products with with the same model.  It then updates all but the first to have the sequential number after the model name:

```
update products p join
       (select p.*,
               (@rn := if(@pm = products_model, @rn + 1,
                          if(@pm := products_model, 1, 1)
                         )
               ) as seqnum
        from products p
        order by products_model
       ) pp
       on p.id = pp.id cross join
       (select @pm := '', @rn := 0) vars
    set products_model = concat_ws('_', products_model, seqnum)
    where seqnum > 1;
```

Comment: I have an error:
where seqnum > 1;
[Err] 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'as seqnum
        from products pI have an error: